# MVC3 to MVC4 upgrade issue

Tags: firefox, asp.net-mvc-4

I've updated my MVC3 site to use MVC4 today and have come across a problem.  When navigating to a particular url (the url for an MVC area) I get this messaage in Firefox

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

This used to work with MVC4.  Chrome still does work with MVC4.

Any ideas?